# Dynamically create array of textboxes and labels winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to create an array of label and text boxes dynamically.

I have a groupBox and I need to add the above to it.
What is the best way to align then correctly?  How do you get the location?

below does not work

```
    public void TestCreateInputLabelAndTextBox()
    {

        foreach (Parameter parameter in Params)
        {
            var lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = "lbl" + parameter.Name;
            lbl.Text = parameter.Name;
            lbl.AutoSize = true;
            lbl.Location = new Point(7, 30);
            lbl.Name = "label1";
            lbl.Size = new Size(35, 13);


            var txtBox = new TextBox();
            txtBox.Name = "txt" + parameter.Name;
            txtBox.Text = parameter.Name;
            txtBox.Location = new Point(20, 20);
            txtBox.Location = new Point(49, 22);
            txtBox.Size = new Size(100, 20);


            groupBox1.Controls.Add(lbl);
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(txtBox);
        }

    }
```

How do you do it?

Comment: How would you calculate their locations with pen-and-paper?  Try that first, then take your logic and convert it to code.

Comment: Consider ditching the labels and textboxes and use a datagridview instead.  Then all you need to do is add rows.

Comment: Use standard containers like `FlowLayoutPanel, TableLayoutPanel`, etc for aligning purpose.

Comment: If they're all going to be the same size, you can have them located at fixed intervals.  You'll need a starting location and then add to that for each new textbox and label.

Comment: The reason you're getting random suggestions is that we don't understand what problem you're trying to solve. **Why** do you need to do this? What "does not work" about what you are doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must make an array of textbox and lable
for example:

```
TextBox[] txt= new TextBox[10];
for (int i = 0; i <=10; i++) {
    txt(i) = new TextBox();
    txt(i).Text = i.Tostring();
    if (i > 0) {
        txt(i).Left = txt(i - 1).Right;
    }

    this.Controls.Add(txt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to comments placed above I have used a tablePanelLayout.

I am sorry that my question seems not to have been clear.
I tried to be as concise as possible because I beleive that the more you say the more you can confuse somebody who might help you.

All I needed was some pointers.By using a tablePanellayout solved my problem.
thanks for your comments