# How to create many labels and textboxes dynamically depending on the value of an integer variable?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to dynamically create and display 'n' Labels with 'n' corresponding Textboxs when we know value of 'n' after for example, clicking "Display" button.

Let me know if anything make you don't understand my question. Thank you!

I am working with VS C# Express 2010 Windows Form.

Comment: Your spelling is incredible creative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically create array of textboxes and labels winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157369/dynamically-create-array-of-textboxes-and-labels-winforms)

Comment: @UweKeim My bad Eng, but I think it was really incredibly creative LOL

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This can be broken out into several sub-problems, and we don't know for which sub-problem(s) you need help.

Comment: @mbeckish At first, I want to know is that possible to do that, then find out what other problems after I tried.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would create a user control which holds a Label and a Text Box in it and simply create instances of that user control 'n' times. If you want to know a better way to do it and use properties to get access to the values of Label and Text Box from the user control, please let me know.

Simple way to do it would be:

```
int n = 4; // Or whatever value - n has to be global so that the event handler can access it

private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox[] textBoxes = new TextBox[n];
    Label[] labels = new Label[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        textBoxes[i] = new TextBox();
        // Here you can modify the value of the textbox which is at textBoxes[i]

        labels[i] = new Label();
        // Here you can modify the value of the label which is at labels[i]
    }

    // This adds the controls to the form (you will need to specify thier co-ordinates etc. first)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(textBoxes[i]);
        this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
    }
}
```

The code above assumes that you have a button `btnDisplay` and it has a `onClick` event assigned to `btnDisplay_Click` event handler. You also need to know the value of n and need a way of figuring out where to place all controls. Controls should have a width and height specified as well.

To do it using a User Control simply do this.

Okay, first of all go and create a new user control and put a text box and label in it.

Lets say they are called `txtSomeTextBox` and `lblSomeLabel`. In the code behind add this code:

```
public string GetTextBoxValue() 
{ 
    return this.txtSomeTextBox.Text; 
} 

public string GetLabelValue() 
{ 
    return this.lblSomeLabel.Text; 
} 

public void SetTextBoxValue(string newText) 
{ 
    this.txtSomeTextBox.Text = newText; 
} 

public void SetLabelValue(string newText) 
{ 
    this.lblSomeLabel.Text = newText; 
}
```

Now the code to generate the user control will look like this (MyUserControl is the name you have give to your user control):

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControl[] controls = new MyUserControl[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        controls[i] = new MyUserControl();

        controls[i].setTextBoxValue("some value to display in text");
        controls[i].setLabelValue("some value to display in label");
        // Now if you write controls[i].getTextBoxValue() it will return "some value to display in text" and controls[i].getLabelValue() will return "some value to display in label". These value will also be displayed in the user control.
    }

    // This adds the controls to the form (you will need to specify thier co-ordinates etc. first)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(controls[i]);
    }
}
```

Of course you can create more methods in the usercontrol to access properties and set them. Or simply if you have to access a lot, just put in these two variables and you can access the textbox and label directly:

```
public TextBox myTextBox;
public Label myLabel;
```

In the constructor of the user control do this:

```
myTextBox = this.txtSomeTextBox;
myLabel = this.lblSomeLabel;
```

Then in your program if you want to modify the text value of either just do this.

```
control[i].myTextBox.Text = "some random text"; // Same applies to myLabel
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Hi, yes I want to access value of Label and TextBox, could you please advise?

Comment: If you can append your answer with your new sample codes that with be great because sometimes I may think in different ways.

Comment: here you go mate, if you need it clearer or some actual project sample, please let me know

Comment: Hi, How to create a new user control?

Comment: Right click on the project, go to Add and click on User Control. Then call it whatever you want it to be. Add the text box and label to it and call them appropriately, then you can position them the way you want

Comment: Hey, I've added a sample project which does exactly what I've explained. I created it using VS2010 so it should be compatible with Visual C# Express 2010

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple example that should let you keep going add somethink that would act as a placeholder to your winform can be  `TableLayoutPanel`

and then just add controls to it

```
   for ( int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++ ) {


    Label lblTitle = new Label();
    lblTitle.Text = i+"Your Text";
    youlayOut.Controls.Add( lblTitle, 0, i );

    TextBox txtValue = new TextBox();
    youlayOut.Controls.Add( txtValue, 2, i );
}
```

Comment: this answer is semi-dynamic

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a button that when pressed sets n to 5, you could then generate labels and textboxes on your form like so.

```
var n = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    //Create label
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = String.Format("Label {0}", i);
    //Position label on screen
    label.Left = 10;
    label.Top = (i + 1) * 20;
    //Create textbox
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    //Position textbox on screen
    textBox.Left = 120;
    textBox.Top = (i + 1) * 20;
    //Add controls to form
    this.Controls.Add(label);
    this.Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

This will not only add them to the form but position them decently as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
int cleft = 1;
intaleft = 1;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     TextBox txt = new TextBox();
     this.Controls.Add(txt);
     txt.Top = cleft * 40;
     txt.Size = new Size(200, 16);
     txt.Left = 150;
     cleft = cleft + 1;
     Label lbl = new Label();
     this.Controls.Add(lbl);
     lbl.Top = aleft * 40;
     lbl.Size = new Size(100, 16);
     lbl.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
     lbl.Text = "BoxNo/CardNo";
     lbl.Left = 70;
     aleft = aleft + 1;
     return;
}
private void btd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //Here you Delete Text Box One By One(int ix for Text Box)
    for (int ix = this.Controls.Count - 2; ix >= 0; ix--)
    //Here you Delete Lable One By One(int ix for Lable)
    for (int x = this.Controls.Count - 2; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        if (this.Controls[ix] is TextBox) 
        this.Controls[ix].Dispose();
        if (this.Controls[x] is Label) 
        this.Controls[x].Dispose();
        return;
    }
}
```