# Input from C# Dynamically Created Text Boxes

Tags: c#, dynamic, textbox

I am using some code I found in one of the solutions here to dynamically generate labels and text boxes on a form while the program is running.  The code to generate the labels and boxes works fine.  My problem is that I will need to be able to do something with the input from the user into those text boxes which were dynamically created, but I'm not sure how to access the user's input in order to define it as a variable.  Thank you for your help.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int intGroups = Convert.ToInt32(maskedTextBox1.Text);
        int n = intGroups;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            //Retrieved from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008871/how-to-create-many-labels-and-textboxes-dynamically-depending-on-the-value-of-an                
            //Create label
            Label portTypeLabel = new Label();
            portTypeLabel.Text = String.Format("Port Type (FastEthernet/GigabitEthernet) {0}", i);

            Label portGroupLabel = new Label();
            portTypeLabel.Text = String.Format("Port Group (the first number before the slash, usually 1) {0}", i);

            Label startIntNumLabel = new Label();
            portTypeLabel.Text = String.Format("Group {0} starting interface number", i);

                            //Position label on screen
            portTypeLabel.Left = 10;
            portTypeLabel.Top = (i) * 20;
            /* Must add the rest of the code for displaying the labels here
            */
            //Create textbox
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
            //Position textbox on screen
            textBox.Left = 120;
            textBox.Top = (i) * 20;
            combo.Left = 120;
            combo.Top = (i) * 20;
            //Add controls to form
            this.Controls.Add(portTypeLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(textBox);
            this.Controls.Add(combo);
        }
```

Comment: One way I do this is to add each text box to an array/list of all of them as I add them to the form, so that I can keep track of their values without explicitly referring to them

Comment: You dont need `n` sets of controls to get `n` sets of input - they are reusable.  Add a button for the user to `Add another` to signal you to collect the input and clear the controls

Comment: Plutonix, that's a good point.  If it was just something for me, I would be all over that.  However, I'm going to hopefully be distributing it to less than tech savvy people.  I think it would be better for them to see everything ip front.  But thank you for that reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to give the controls some names to access them easily.

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Name = "textbox" + i.ToString();
```

Second, if you need to create method for selection you will need to define event

```
textBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TextChanged);
```

In this method you can put switch..case to check with textbox fire the event (maybe using the number at the end).

```
void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
    // t is the textbox you referred
    MessageBox.Show(t.Name);
}
```

Comment: It's almost midnight here, and I am about to go to sleep.  However, that seems so simple it will probably work for what I'm trying to do.  I will give this a shot tomorrow and post my results.  Thank you for the swift response!

Comment: The first part worked just fine.  However, the second part throws an error saying that the ".TextChanged" event can only be on the left side of an += operator.  However, this is getting me much farther than I would have thought.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry for doing this, but after working with this code, I simply cannot figure out how to get the method for selection to work.  Additionally, I cannot seem to reference the text boxes, even after they are named.  Any ideas on why that may be?  Thank you again.