# c# How to display multiple dynamic labels and buttons?

Tags: c#, .net

I am a newbie to c#. I am trying to build an application which prints the result from the labels. I have 2 forms in which form1 returns the values to form2. I have used get and set methods to display those values in form2. I just want to display those values in multiple labels on form2 and display a button in front of each label..

```
namespace Loans
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Label labels = new Label();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string DisplayThis
        {
            get
            {
                labels= new Label(); //cant create multiple labels
                return labels.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                labels.Text = value;
            }
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
            int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you are trying to do. Your code isn't doing anything with the labels so it's impossible to know what you want to achieve.

Comment: Event to create button?

Comment: I have 2 forms in which form1 form returns the values to  form2. I have used get and set methods to display those values in form2. I just want to display those values in multiple labels on form 2.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009171/6112401. Hope to help you!