# Create new textboxes from Variable value

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a program that requires me to ask a user for an input value which then will be used to create a certain amount of textboxes depending on the user input value. Then I should be able to input a value into these textboxes and add them together to form a total. Is there a control that would let me do this easier? If I create new TextBox controls how would I go about getting the name of them since they won't have been created until the user inputs a value of how many to make. depending on the user input there could be a larger or smaller value.

I am unsure of how to go about this. Could anyone give me a pointer? Here's my code so far and a picture of my Design

```
double totalBudget;
double totalBills;
int monthPicked;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    totalBills = Double.Parse(billAmount.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < totalBills; i++)
    {
        //Create label
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = "Bill" + (i+1);
        //Position label on screen
        label.Left = 440;
        label.Top = (i + 1) * 22;
        //Create textbox
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        //Position textbox on screen
        textBox.Left = 540;
        textBox.Top = (i + 1) * 20;
        //Add controls to form
        this.Controls.Add(label);
        this.Controls.Add(textBox);
    }
}
```

Here's my Design view:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create many labels and textboxes dynamically depending on the value of an integer variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008871/how-to-create-many-labels-and-textboxes-dynamically-depending-on-the-value-of-an)

Answer (score 0):

I just set up a simple algorithm for you to generate textboxes based on the number entered from the keyboard. You can develop and use it however you want.

```
private TextBox[] txtNumber;

    private int count;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

        txtNumber = new TextBox[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

        {
            txtNumber[i] = new TextBox();

            txtNumber[i].Multiline = true;

            txtNumber[i].ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;

            txtNumber[i].Location = new Point(10, 90 * i);

            txtNumber[i].Size = new Size(200, 60);

            this.Controls.Add(txtNumber[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a control that would let me do this easier?

Yes. It's called a datagridview. You can conceive it as a huge array of textboxes, it looks like Excel and it's how most of us would design a program where a variable number of things can be entered into something that looks like a spreadsheet

You don't need to ask the user how many boxes; a datagridview will just expand automatically the more lines they enter

I'll work with what you apparently have already

- make sure you're creating a .net framework app, not a .net core app - at the time of writing core has some fairly blocking bugs that cripple the designer and make it impossible to complete these instructions
- swap those textboxes for nunericupdowns
- add a new file of type DataSet to your project, call it HouseholdDataSet
- open it, right click the surface, add a datatable and call it Expenditures or similar
- right click add a column called Month, of datatype string; then a column for BillsAmount type double, then another column for Budget, again double
- add a column called BillsTotal, same datatype as the BillsAmount and set it's Expression to `SUM([BillsAmount])`
- save, switch to form designer
- open the data sources panel from the view menu/other windows
- drag the node called "Expenditures" out of the panel and onto the grid
- expand the expenditures node, look for total, pop the drop down next to it, choose Label (I think there is a label option in there, if not just make it a textbox and set it to borderless readonly after you drop it on the form so it looks like a label) and then drag the BillsTotal node into the form
- switch to code view in the click handler of your button and put this line of code

```
householdDataSet.Expenditures.AddExpendituresRow(monthList.SelectedItem.ToString(), (double)billsAmountNumericUpDown.Value, (double)budgetAmountNumericUpDown.Value);
```

You'll probably have to tweak the code line a little - I've guessed at how you've named stuff

That's it. Adding the row to the datatable Expenditures will cause it to show inside the datagridview, The Total column will update automatically worth the new amount, the label/textbox connected to the total will update automatically, and you can select any line of the grid and edit the amounts